# Checking a mastermind answer as fast as possible

Tags: algorithm, c

This is not your typical mastermind question, I am not trying to find the **right** answer. Merely to *check* the answer and provide a result as fast as possible. The function signature cannot be changed, however the contents are just my best guess. Here's what I've come up with :

```c
typedef int Code[100]; /* Arbitrary size */

void check_answer(
    int        code_length, /* Effective length of the code */
    const Code answer,      /* Answer to check */
    const Code code,        /* The actual code */
    int        *black,      /* Returns count of right digits in right place */
    int        *white       /* Returns count of right digits in wrong place */
) {
    Code code_mask;   /* Masks already-matched digits of the actual code */
    Code answer_mask; /* Masks already-matched digits of the answer code */
    int i, j;

    *black = 0;
    *white = 0;

    /* Count black pegs */
    for ( i = 0; i < code_length; i++ ) {
        if ( answer[ i ] == code[ i ] ) {
            *black          += 1;
            code_mask[ i ]   = 1;
            answer_mask[ i ] = 1;
        } else {
            code_mask[ i ]   = 0;
            answer_mask[ i ] = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Count white pegs */
    for ( i = 0; i < code_length; i++ ) {
        if ( answer_mask[ i ] ) continue; /* Skip already matched */
        for ( j = 0; j < code_length; j++ ) {

            /*
                Skip already-matched or same-index :
                If mask is 0, same-index is necessarily different
            */
            if ( code_mask[ j ] || i == j ) continue;

            if ( answer[ i ] == code[ j ] ) {
                *white += 1;
                code_mask[ j ] = 1; /* Mask code only, previous answer_mask entries are never used again */
                break; /* Answer digit is matched, skip to next */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Context : In this exercise, the solver algorithm uses this same function to check whether each *potential* next guess, were it to be the actual code, would produce the same answers for previously submitted guesses. Once it finds such a guess, it submits it to be tested against the real code.

The goal is to be as fast as possible with this algorithm structure, the `check_answer` function being the critical hot-path. For a 12-color 9-digit code, it is called in the order of 10 billion times.

Comment: "As fast as possible" is a lofty goal.. Can you use SIMD, and which kind? What range of values can `code_length` have? What is the maximum color?

Comment: @harold I can use SIMD, it only needs to work with GCC on Linux. Both length and number of colours depend on arguments, however reasonable maximums would be length 32 with 255 colours. I've tried making the codes `unsigned char` arrays, no observable difference.

Comment: If the number of colors and `code_length` were limited to 64, that would (probably? I didn't work it out) allow a nice implementation of the white pegs based on bitmasks (no arrays, no searching)

Comment: @harold Can you explicit a little more ? I'm not sure I understand what you mean, especially since you said white pegs. The black ones seem easier to `SIMD` via bitwise `and`, although we'd still have to iterate through the resulting array to obtain the total, so I'm not certain if it would be faster.

Comment: The black ones could be counted by doing a SIMD comparison, turning it into a bitmask of comparison results, and popcounting that mask. Some iteration is necessary if there are more elements than can fit in a SIMD register, but much fewer iterations than the number of elements.

Comment: `signature cannot be changed, however the contents are just my best guess` *the **comments** are…*?

Comment: *as fast as possible **with this algorithm structure*** I almost went on to target this in an answer. I take it to be about checking all possible codes in some order, but this is a disadvantageous way to go about design&implementation improvement in general. Compare *[best] to meet goals*.

Comment: @ice-wind "For a 12-color 9-digit code, it is called in the order of 10 billion times." ---> What is the maximum number of "colors"?

Answer (score 3):

There's some low-hanging fruit getting rid of an `if/else`:

```
    for ( i = 0; i < code_length; i++ ) {
        int r = ( answer[ i ] == code[ i ] );
        *black          += r;
        code_mask[ i ]   = r;
        answer_mask[ i ] = r;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Having had some time to kill, below is code for the game "mastermind" that uses lowercase alpha characters instead of colours. The game reveals the random collection of letters for testing that the somewhat improved *tallying* of points is easy to test and confirm. I've taken liberties, using character arrays instead of the OP's integer arrays. It should be a small issue to adapt this implementation to suit one's needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 6 // "width" of the game board

// Fill array with random collection of chars from 'a' to 'a'+N-1
void gen( char buf[], size_t n ) {
    while( n-- )
        buf[n] = (char)((rand()%N) + 'a');
}

void check_answer( int len, char *poss, char *actl, int *black, int *white ) {
    int a[N] = { 0 }; // tally actual but not guessed
    int g[N] = { 0 }; // tally guessed but not actual

    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        int r = poss[ i ] == actl[ i ]; // matching?
        *black += r;
        a[ actl[i] - 'a' ] += !r; // count not matching
        g[ poss[i] - 'a' ] += !r; // both actual and guessed.
    }

    for( int x = 0; x < len; x++ )
        *white += g[x] < a[x] ? g[x] : a[x]; // credit minimum of guesses
}

int main( void ) {
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    char ans[ N + 1 ];
    gen( ans, N );

    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        putchar( ans[i] ), putchar( ' ' );
    putchar( '\n' );

    for( ;; ) {
        char guess[ 128 ];

        printf( "Guess: " );
        fgets( guess, sizeof guess, stdin );

        int black = 0;
        int white = 0;
        check_answer( N, guess, ans, &black, &white );
        printf( "black %d, white %d\n", black, white );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Play:

```
d b b d b a  // <== Normally not revealed at the beginning of the game
Guess: cccccc
black 0, white 0
Guess: bddbab
black 0, white 6
Guess: dbbadb
black 3, white 3
Guess: dbbdba
black 6, white 0
Guess:
```

Because this is a toy written to get the evaluation function to work quickly, error handling has not been given much attention.

If one wants 12 "colours" for a game board of "9 digits", one need only add another `#define M 12` and change the applicable `N`s to `M`s...

Comment: Unlike other times I've seen such "get rid of an if" hacks, this does seem to actually result in fewer instructions !

Comment: @ice-wind branchlfree tricks can also be faster when they cost more instructions, they can also be slower but don't discount them based on instruction count: instruction count does not have such a simple relationship to speed

Comment: @harold "Tricks?!!" How about "techniques", instead. `:-)`

Comment: @harold Oh that's interesting, I didn't know higher instruction counts could be faster ! Is that also true for RISC systems though ? Supposedly all instructions should take the same amount of clock cycles ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @ice-wind Not really, RISC does not promise that all instructions cost the same. That's not reasonably attainable for high-performance designs [such as Apple M1](https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm.html), which make cheap instructions like `add` so cheap that it's unreasonable to make more-complicated instructions similarly cheap. I didn't mean complex CISC instructions anyway, just basic things like `add` vs `mul` or the variable (and sometimes high) cost of branching and so on.

Comment: @ice-wind I was expecting to read your benchmarking results...

Answer (score 1):

The nesting of loops is a danger sign that this scales poorly as code length increases:

> ```
> for ( i = 0; i < code_length; i++ ) {
>     if ( answer_mask[ i ] ) continue; /* Skip already matched */
>     for ( j = 0; j < code_length; j++ ) {
>         if ( code_mask[ j ] || i == j ) continue;
> ```

Since `code_length` can be anything up to 100, according to the `Code` typedef, we have around 100² iterations here.  (I'd do the move `i==j` test before the one that indexes `code_mask`, just as a micro change that a compiler might not be able to spot, if I were keeping that structure)

At this point, if the range of colour choices is reasonable, we want to transform to *histograms* counting the occurrence of each value in the code and answer.  Then the result is the size of intersection of those histograms.

Conveniently, we have the black-counting loop available in which to gather the histogram data:

```
    /* assume colour values fit in char */
    unsigned code_hist[UCHAR_MAX+1] = { 0 };
    unsigned answer_hist[UCHAR_MAX+1] = { 0 };

    /* Count black pegs */
    for (int i = 0;  i < code_length;  ++i) {
        if (answer[i] == code[i]) {
            ++*black;
        } else {
            ++code_hist[(unsigned char)code[i]];
            ++answer_hist[(unsigned char)answer[i]];
        }
    }
```

Note that we no longer need the "mask" variables to track what we've already seen.

Counting the white pegs becomes a straightforward loop over the number of colours:

```
    /* Count white pegs */
    for (unsigned i = 0;  i <= UCHAR_MAX;  ++i) {
        *white += answer_hist[i] < code_hist[i] ? answer_hist[i] : code_hist[i];
    }
```

However, this is only an improvement when colours are small integers.  Otherwise we likely need a full hash-map implementation to store the histograms (and we'd be better off simply sorting the values, and using a modified merge to count matches).

Comment: Oops, indeed - now fixed.  :)